# How to search particular value from column

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a number of advance_criteria. inserted all select query in advance_criteria column. i am search for only company code is 17,41 from advance_criteria column. For example when i am trying below query executed.

```
    with Criteria as 
    (
    select 'SELECT ''Y'' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE 
                ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN (17,41)' Advance_Criteria , '1'Col_Id from dual
                
     union all
    select 'select * FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP where QP.COMPANY_CODE       IN (''01'')' Advance_Criteria , '2'Col_Id from dual
    union all
    select 'SELECT ''Y'' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE 
                ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN (''17'',''41'')' Advance_Criteria , '3'Col_Id from dual
    union all
    select '
V_RETURN := K_DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_MANAGEMENT.F_CHECK_FORM_ON_ENDT(P_ENTITY_REFERENCE,P_ENTITY_TYPE, ''17399 0741'');

select * FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP where QP.COMPANY_CODE       IN (01, 02, 06, 41, 17)' Advance_Criteria , '4'Col_Id from dual
    union all
    select 'select DECODE (COUNT(1),0,1,0)
        INTO V_RETURN
        FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP,
        where QP.COMPANY_CODE IN (''01'',''02'',''06'',''17'',''41'')
        and QP.PRIMARY_STATE_CODE = ''WA''' Advance_Criteria , '5'Col_Id from dual
    union all
    select 'select 1 from vw_mis_quote_policies 
           WHERE  PROGRAM_CODE IN ( ''29'',''40'', ''46'', ''47'', ''48'')
          AND COMPANY_CODE IN (''01'',''02'',''06'',''09'',''29'')' Advance_Criteria , '6'Col_Id from dual
    union all
    select 'select * FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP where QP.COMPANY_CODE       IN (01, 02, 06)' Advance_Criteria , '7'Col_Id from dual
    )
    select * from Criteria where upper(Advance_Criteria) like upper('%COMPANY_CODE IN (17,41)%') 
    or
    Advance_Criteria like upper('%company_code in (''17'',''41'')%');
```

I showed the following output after executing the query.

```
ADVANCE_CRITERIA                                                                 COL_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"SELECT 'Y' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE 
ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN (17,41)"                  1
"SELECT 'Y' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE 
ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN ('17','41')"              3
```

**The expectation result**

in Advance_Criteria column the search COMPANY_CODE is 17 and 41
like col_id 1,3,4,5,6

Comment: Sorry, but - what is expected result? You wrote a *sentence* ("the only show the COMPANY_CODE is 17 and 41") but what does that mean? What is query exactly supposed to return?

Comment: @Littlefoot please execute my above query i want only COL_ID 1,3,4,5,6

Comment: The expected result still isn't clear, nor is it clear why the actual result is unexpected. Also, [why](https://xyproblem.info/) are you using dynamic SQL, especially since it isn't even creating dynamic queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
select *
from   Criteria
where  REGEXP_LIKE(
         Advance_Criteria,
         'COMPANY_CODE\s+IN\s+\((\s*'
           || '(\d+\s*,\s*)*?17\s*,\s*(\d+\s*,\s*)*?41(\s*,\s*\d+)*|'
           || '(\d+\s*,\s*)*?41\s*,\s*(\d+\s*,\s*)*?17(\s*,\s*\d+)*|'
           || q'[('\d+'\s*,\s*)*'17'\s*,\s*('\d+'\s*,\s*)*'41'(\s*,\s*'\d+')*|]'
           || q'[('\d+'\s*,\s*)*'41'\s*,\s*('\d+'\s*,\s*)*'17'(\s*,\s*'\d+')*]'
           || '\s*)\)',
         'i'
       );
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | ADVANCE_CRITERIA | COL_ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | SELECT 'Y' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN (17,41) | 1 |
> | SELECT 'Y' FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES WHERE ENTITY_REFERENCE = P_ENTITY_REFERENCE and COMPANY_CODE IN ('17','41') | 3 |
> | select * FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP where QP.COMPANY_CODE IN (01, 02, 06, 41, 17) | 4 |
> | select DECODE (COUNT(1),0,1,0) INTO V_RETURN FROM VW_MIS_QUOTE_POLICIES QP, where QP.COMPANY_CODE IN ('01','02','06','17','41') and QP.PRIMARY_STATE_CODE = 'WA' | 5 |

*Note: #6 does not match as it does not contain 17 or 41.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b18f37fe31b2e2609c84e49a3616d9cf)*